# object doesn't support this action

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<select id="country" multiple="multiple"><option>Albania</option><option>Bangladesh</option><option>China</option><option>India</option></select>

<a onclick="submit()">submit</a>
```

JS:

```
function submit(){
  var selected = [];
  $("#country option:selected").each(function(){
     selected.push($(this).text());
  });
  alert(selected);
}
```

When i click on submit i am getting "object doesn't support this action" error!! any solutions ?

Comment: Tons of syntax errors for example, `function({` Please see the console.

Comment: `onLick` Uh oh!!! When this event will get fired?? while licking?? :) :)

Comment: Raj: it typo error - here - actually i written correct...

Comment: another typo: `.each(function({` should be `.each(function(){`

Comment: ok, please sugges the solution for the issue... the option:selected method will not support in IE, do we need to use any other ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/osanL90w/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that one is nice _while licking_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your submit function declaration: replace it with

```
submit = function() {
   ...
}
```

[Here's JSFiddle snippet in which I got your code running](http://jsfiddle.net/or3vhbns/)